# asp.net mvc: allow multiple input-formats for a input field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-modeling

I want to allow multiple input-formats for a input field. In my case it is a Longitude field. In the DB I set it to decimal(18,10). It expects to recieve a comma-separated-value e.g. 16,2345678 but Google Maps or some Users are using a dot e.g. 16.2345678 
I dont want to return an error but simply be glad and transform it to the expected db-format.

I tried to do it in my MetaData Validation Class (using Entity Framework)

```
public partial class Job

    /*[Bind(Exclude = "ID")]*/
    public class JobMetaData
    {
        public object Longitude
        {
            get { return this.Longitude; }
            set { this.Longitude = value; /* Seems that this point isnt reached*/ }
        }
```

but unfortunatly the setter is not called and the ViewState.isValid returns simply false.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Job model)
    {

        // parse the long-lat if needed here??

        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
```

Where should I try to parse the value to allow both values (comma-separated and dot-separated) transform them and safe it.

I have the same issue for another field: I would like the user to enter 4 or 4€, in case just delete the €-sign and save it as a number to db.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your get;set; looks like recursion to me

Comment: seems like. But I'm note sure. Its a partial class and in the "other part" of this partial class there is also a property Longitude with get/set (the EntityFramework Class). It seems that that this get/set isnt actually called at all, therefore I cannot do any preprocessing..

Answer (score 1):

If you have same issue for another field.
as a best practise -
1] use ViewModel "JobViewModel"

2] so that If required you can create Custom validation attributes  for your other properties

3]  In Edit Post accept ViewModel.
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Job model)
    {

```
    // parse the long-lat if needed here??

    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
```

4] and if Modellstate isValid perform required parsing and then save it to database.

**EDIT**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(JobViewModel jobviewModel)
    {
    try
        {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            jobviewModel.Longitude.replace(".",",")
            -- save DB logic here

        }

    }

    }

public class JobViewModel 
{
    public string Longitude{ get; set; }
}


For GET methods need to use use Automapper. or 

    jobviewModel.Longitude = model.Longitude
```

Comment: With custom validation attributes, how is it possible to do any preprocessing? Inside such a custom attibute definition there is a method isValid returning true/false but its not possible to correct a value if necessary - I can return true for validation, but the wrong value will be passed to the db which will raise an error. Did I loose something?

Comment: @LukeSolar You are correct. Custom validation attribute will provide you Isvalid method to return true or flase- but using viewmodel is a recommended practise for MVC project and this will help you to modify values as per your requirement and then save modified viewmodel into database.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709429/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-tips-and-tricks

Comment: @swapneel If I have a model job containing Title, Longitude, etc. (generated, Entity Framework), My ViewModel just contains this Model job. Where should I implement the preprocessing after the post? can you post an example?

Comment: @swapneel thanks for the link, nice ressource but I could not find the answer to the question above.

Comment: @LukeSolar -see my EDIT - is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Use the string type and do whatever you want with it.

```
public partial class Job
{
    public class JobMetaData
    {
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Oennning Unfortunately it doesnt work. The EF-Model itself is generated from DB containing some basic validation (the type, required). This JobMetaData Class adds other valiation attributes on top of them. I thought it would make sense to add some preprocessing in this place. I admit Im not sure if I got you right?